# Como alterar a classe de um elemento ao clicar em outro utilizando Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Estou construindo um sistema de comentários e gostaria que ao clicar em um botão, um formulário de resposta aparecesse. o problema é que há um formulário de resposta para cada comentário, e eu gostaria que só aparecesse o formulário de resposta do elemento que eu cliquei.
Segue a base do código, sendo "resposta" a classe do botão para chamar o formulário "formularioResposta".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".resposta").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(.formularioResposta).addClass('selecionado');
        $(".selecionado").show(3000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `closest`, `siblings`, `parent` (o que determina o uso deles é a hierarquia dos elementos, ou seja como está o HTML, *o que não está em sua pergunta*), por exemplo:

```
$(".resposta").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('.formularioResposta').addClass('selecionado');
    $(".selecionado").show(3000);
});
```

**Demonstração:**

```js
$('.formularioResposta').hide();

$(".resposta").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  campoComentario = $(this).siblings('.formularioResposta');

  if (campoComentario.is('.selecionado')) {
    campoComentario.removeClass('selecionado').hide(300);
  } else {
    campoComentario.addClass('selecionado').show(300);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="resposta"> Responder</div>
  <div class="formularioResposta"><textarea></textarea></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="resposta"> Responder</div>
  <div class="formularioResposta"><textarea></textarea></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="resposta"> Responder</div>
  <div class="formularioResposta"><textarea></textarea></div>
</div>
```